# how to get the last match in a string builder in java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

i have a string builder like this

"abc efg abc hij abc klm"

i want to get the last abc from this string and also the data's following the last match. How to do this in java?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)

Answer (score 1):

```
 StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("abc efg abc hij abc klm");
 int index = text.lastIndexOf("abc");
 String substring = text.toString().substring(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

As follows:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append("abc efg abc hij abc klm");
int lastIndex = buffer.lastIndexOf("abc");
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    System.out.println(buffer.substring(lastIndex));
}
```